How to Add html page dynamically in my Spring Boot project and save them also
I am a Computer Science student working on a project of my WEB Development Course in my university , my project is about the University's Club Management System , my project supervisor has asked me to strictly use Java Spring Boot in my backend , I am using basic HTML , CSS , JAVASCRIPT in my frontend . now i am stuck in a process , recently he has asked me to implement some features in my project but i don't understand how could i implement those. I am using VS Code as my IDE and using VS Code extensions to support my backend , I have used basic html , CSS , JavaScript in frontend.

When someone register in my website he would be either USER or ADMIN
USERs can only join in CLUBs
ADMINs can join CLUBs and also can CREATE new clubs
if a ADMIN wants to create new club he must fill up a form where he will nedd to submit some info (Club's name , Club's president's name , his social media links , vice President's name , his social media links , their photos , club's motto , mission and vision , some photos of that club etc. ) which must be editable in future
the moment he submits the form a new club box should appear in the welcome.html as well as in index.html and in the database the data must be stored for further query
now anyone can join that new club
Every time someone logs in he will see the new club in the all club's list and can join that club
a user can also shift his account as an admin and so on

here is my GitHub repository of the project stage i am currently in https://github.com/neonion12/Project_3100 feel free to suggest me as my project submission deadline is near. ADVANCE THANKS & HAPPY CODING.
I am expecting a supportive response as soon as possible .

Please read this open letter which explains to great lengths why this is not an acceptable question here as it is and suggest how to proceed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
